# How to use yum to install from a DVD

Tags: fedora, yum

I use Fedora 14. Some days ago, I used the command `yum remove openoffice.org-*` and removed openoffice successfully. The, I wanted to get it back. I have all the packages and dependancies required to install in an installation dvd. The problem is that when I try to manually install each package, **yum** does not check dependencies in the DVD. How can I configure yum to look for all dependancies and packages required, in the DVD?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions is a better place to ask

Comment: So why is this tagged fedora12??????

Comment: I updated the tags

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need to update your `/etc/yum.repos.d` to include your dvd. See here for details: [Howto Setup yum repositories to update or install package from ISO CDROM Image](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/redhat-centos-fedora-linux-setup-repo.html)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest thing to do here, to just fix this problem, is to install the "yum-plugin-tmprepo" plugin and do:

```
yum history undo <transaction id> --tmprepo=/path/to/DVD/packages
```

...where you can get the transaction ID from `yum history list openoffice`.